# Power BI: How to scenario analysis, where the selector "looks up" the select value from slicer and gets values from that row

Tags: powerbi, lookup, analysis, scenarios

I've followed multiple tutorials on scenario analysis and what if analysis in power BI. these examples are quite clear to me and I somewhat understand how they work. For example this (https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Scenario-Analysis-What-Ifs-Tips-amp-Techniques-For-Power-BI/ba-p/559653).

In this example they create a table that contains values for different scenarios

5%
10%
15%
20%

etc. and the user of the report can select these. But what if instead of direct values I have categorical values, such as "Low, medium, high, very high" like:

```
category - trend rise
low         5%
medium      10%
high        15%
very high   20%
```

On my other table I have:

```
Value - Item - trend_default
10       A      0.3
15       A      0.2
20       B      0.4
25       B      0.15
35       C      0.10
30       C      0.05
```

Now with a slicer I want to first select none, one or all of Items, after which I want to select which trend rise I want to apply on selected items(low, medium, high or very high). If I select only item A then Item B and C use their trend_default value in the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

You can create your disconnected table with more than one column, like your example.

Then create a measure, based on the selected value of that table. Something like:

```
Value + Trend Rise = 
    VAR Multiplier = 
        1 + IF ( 
            HASONEVALUE ( 'Scenario - Trend'[Category] ),
            VALUES ( 'Scenario - Trend'[Trend Rise] ),
            0
        )
    RETURN
        SUM ( 'Demo Fact Table'[Value] ) * Multiplier
```

See https://pwrbi.com/so_55281950/ for worked example PBIX file

### UPDATE, BASED ON EDITED QUESTION:

First, create a disconnected dimension table to choose (slice) your Items:

```
Item Chooser = 
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( 
        'Demo Fact Table'[Item]
    )
```

Now you can use measure:

```
Value + Trend = 
    SUMX ( 
        'Demo Fact Table',
        'Demo Fact Table'[Value] * 
            ( 1 +
                IF ( 
                    ISFILTERED ( 'Item Chooser'[Item] ) &&
                    CONTAINS ( 
                        'Item Chooser',
                        'Item Chooser'[Item],
                        'Demo Fact Table'[Item]
                    ) && 
                    HASONEVALUE ( 'Scenario - Trend'[Category] ),
                    VALUES ( 'Scenario - Trend'[Trend Rise] ),
                    'Demo Fact Table'[trend_default]
                )
            )
        )
```

It should be straightforward to modify this if you wanted to return a default trend value per item, from a related item table.

Updated example file: https://pwrbi.com/so_55281950-2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I might have oversimplified my problem since, despite answering my question I'm still not 100% sure how to progress. So what if instead of one fixed "trend rise" I select which columns I want to "apply" the trend rise on. So in your given example, what if I first have a slicer where I select from [Item] A,B or C. and based on those I can select none, one or all. and then apply the selected Trend rise on the selected items, and on other items apply their default "trend rise" which is also column in the "demo fact table" (in your case). I updated the: https://file.io/5YDn72

Comment: Anyway, its basically a mimic of your file with the added "default_Trend" column.

Comment: Seems the file is only available for a limited amount of time. I added a a third column in the "demo fact table" with made up "default_trends" and a slicer on the report which lets the user pick what "Item"s to apply the trend_rise on.

Comment: Would your default trend not be set per item?

Comment: Hmm yeah youre correct. One item would have one default trend.

Comment: Thanks, this suggested solution looks very good. In my case I have a hierarchy of categories from which to choose the trend value (Item) from. So I might have positive trends, negative trends, neutral trends, under which Ill have different years, under which ill have the categories, as seen in my question. I've specified the question a bit more, do you think you could have a look? I think I'm close to solving it but missing some piece.

Comment: LIke how I understand the code is that the CONTAINS clause checks for rows with column values, which then gets returned in case all other variables are True as well. What I would need to do is find the trend_value in one table where  cat1+cat2+cat3 is equal to my slice selections, which is a unique identifier, and use that trend_value instead of the default trend value. In the default_trend value table cat2+cat3 is a unique identifier since it is aggregated on cat2 level.

Comment: I've created a new question regarding the updated question, if you could please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55332313/how-to-apply-contains-clause-on-hierarchical-categories-to-create-scenario-analy