# How to apply CONTAINS clause on hierarchical categories to create scenario analysis in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, analysis, powerquery, scenarios

Building upon the solution given by @olly ([Power BI: How to scenario analysis, where the selector "looks up" the select value from slicer and gets values from that row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55281950/power-bi-how-to-scenario-analysis-where-the-selector-looks-up-the-select-val)) & file: https://pwrbi.com/so_55281950-2/

In the sample file a "what if" or scenario analysis is created. Two slicers are used, one which selects the scenario, and another one which selects the objects to apply the scenario on. @Olly provided a clever solution to deal with the situation:

```
Value + Trend = 
SUMX ( 
    'Demo Fact Table';
    'Demo Fact Table'[Value] * 
        ( 1 +
            IF ( 
                ISFILTERED ( 'Item Chooser'[Item] ) &&
                CONTAINS ( 
                    'Item Chooser';
                    'Item Chooser'[Item];
                    'Demo Fact Table'[Item]
                ) && 
                HASONEVALUE ( 'Scenario - Trend'[Category] );
                VALUES ( 'Scenario - Trend'[Trend Rise] );
                'Demo Fact Table'[trend_default]
            )
        )
    )
```

Building upon this solution I've been trying to apply the same logic, but to my specific problem. In my problem I don't only have a single layer of "categories", but instead hierarchy of 3 levels.
How would I go on about applying the same solution if my categories had hierarchies? So from my slicer I would select three things: Category1, Year and Category2, which would yield the trend_rise for the selection. and would apply this apply this trend_rise on the selected (4th slicer) rows, i.e. (item A,B or/and C)

```
category1      -   Year - Category2 - trend rise
POSITIVE-trends    2018   low         5%
POSITIVE-trends    2018   high        5%
POSITIVE-trends    2017   low         5%
NEGATIVE-trends    2017   very high   -5%
NEUTRAL-trends     2018   low         0%
POSITIVE-trends    2018   high        5%
NEUTRAL-trends     2017   low         5%
NEUTRAL-trends     2016   very high   15%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a small tweak to the measure, to check whether the `trend_rise` field has one value, and if so then use that, otherwise use the default:

```
Value + Trend = 
SUMX ( 
    'Demo Fact Table',
    'Demo Fact Table'[Value] * 
        ( 1 +
            IF ( 
                ISFILTERED ( 'Item Chooser'[Item] ) &&
                CONTAINS ( 
                    'Item Chooser',
                    'Item Chooser'[Item],
                    'Demo Fact Table'[Item]
                ) && 
                HASONEVALUE ( 'Scenario - Trend'[Trend Rise] ),
                VALUES ( 'Scenario - Trend'[Trend Rise] ),
                'Demo Fact Table'[trend_default]
            )
        )
    )
```

Now you can use slicers on all columns of your Scenario table.

See https://pwrbi.com/so_55332313/ for worked example file.

Comment: Thanks, it was a lot easier than the solutions I were trying to implement..If you find the time, could you have a look at this extention of the solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343387/scenario-what-if-analysis-select-multiple-try-multiple-kpi-values-based-on-sl

Comment: Or alternatively, how would I extend this solution to look year on year values, i.e. in my main table I would plot sales per year, and then I could select "positive trends" & "low" (or something) and it would fetch for each year the said value, and in my main table apply different trend for each year.

Comment: Create a measure for each trend value? We're straying off topic of answering programming questions, and moving into report design, now...

Comment: Sorry I'm not following, I would create a seperate measure for each year and hard code the filter in there?